# React native apk does not run on device

Tags: android, react-native

**My project works fine on android emulator**. I signed apk by following the official react-native site. But I got **AAPT2 error** and I solved it by adding 
**android.enableAapt2=false** in ***gradle.properties*** . But **when I run this on my device it is not working as expected**. The app doesnot show placeholders and does not connect to backend. All this works perfectly on emulator. Can any one help?

[image: project on emulator screenshot]

[image: apk installed on device screenshot]

Comment: please update question with error msg.

Comment: I don't have an error message, the project works fine on emulator, but when converted to apk, it doesn't work as expected, please check the screenshot links. Thank you

Comment: what ide are you using for android development.

Comment: I am developing in react native and I use VSCode, Android studio sdk and emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the cause of the error, The error arised because I used the  component of native base, when I removed it, it began to work as expected